# Xamarin.Android Couchbase.Lite Map Reduce

Tags: couchbase-lite

I simply want to create a View that uses Map-Reduce to do this: Say I have Documents for the Automobile Industry. I would like the user to query for a particular Make - say Ford for example. I would like the user to provide the Ford value via an EditText, Tap a Button, and the "Count" be shown in a TextView. So, to clarify, I want to do a count of a certain type of Document using Map-Reduce. I have searched for over 100 hundred hours on this and have not found not one single example - REAL example I mean. (I have read all the docs, only generic examples - no actual examples)
I am an experienced programmer 15+ yrs exp - all I need is one example, and I am good to go.
Can someone please assist me with this?
Thanks,
Don

Answer (score 1):

```
Here is my Actual Code:
string lMS = "MS:5"; // just to show what type of value I am using
var msCount = dbase.GetView ("count_ms");
msCount.SetMapReduce ((doc, emit) => {
    if (doc.ContainsKey ("DT") && doc["DT"].Equals ("P")) {
        if (doc.ContainsKey ("MS") && doc["MS"].Equals (_ms))
        {
            emit (doc ["id"], 1);
        }
    }
},
(keys, values, rereduce) => values.ToList().Count, "1");

var mscView = dbase.GetView ("count_ms");
var query = mscView.CreateQuery ();
query.StartKey = "MS:1";
query.EndKey = "MS:9999";
var queryResults = query.Run ();

var nr = queryResults.Count;  // shows a value of 1 - wrong - should be 40

// the line below is to allow me to put a stop statement to read line above
var dummyForStop = nr;
```

Comment: This produces a count of 1 = at the line indicated above where I put my stop statement.  This is straight from the .cs file itself.

Comment: The start key and end key are based on the emitted start key and end key.  You are emitted the document ID as a key.  Does the document ID conform to the MS:# format?  Perhaps you should be emitting doc["MS"] as the key and something else as the value?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting something like

```
        var docsByMakeCount = _database.GetView("docs_by_make_count");
        docsByMakeCount.SetMapReduce((doc, emit) =>
        {
            if (doc.ContainsKey("Make"))
            {
                emit(doc["Make"], doc);
            }
        },
        (keys, values, rereduce) => values.ToList().Count
        , "1");
```

when you create your view.

and when you use it:

```
        var docsByMake = _database.GetView("docs_by_make_count");
        var query = docsByCity.CreateQuery();

        query.StartKey = Make;
        query.EndKey = Make;

        var queryResults = query.Run();

        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} documents has been retrieved for that query", queryResults.Count));

        if (queryResults.Count == 0) return;

        var documents = queryResults.Select(result => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result.Value, Formatting.Indented)).ToArray();
        var commaSeperaterdDocs = "[" + string.Join(",", documents) + "]";

        DocumentText = commaSeperaterdDocs;
```

In my case Make and DocumentText are properties.

There are some optimizations to be made here, like rereducing, but it's the straight forward way.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  I just saw your answer - I am going to adapt it now to my needs and give it a shot!  Again, Thanks!

Comment: Hi rolikatz, I only get back a count of 1 using this.  The more I use Couchbase - the more I absolutely hate it.  Am forced to use it though.  Maybe if I knew more about it???  The one particular value I am looking for - in my "old" non-cb type query, returns 40, so 1 is sure incorrect.  Maybe I will post the code here.

Comment: Well, I have tried this code - is will never ever produce anything but a count of 1.  Wow, it looks like I am just screwed on the Xamarin.Android side of CB.  There too many little things that happen - like queries only running once, then not again until the app is closed.  My employer is suggesting moving to Android Studio.

Comment: Hi, The count is indeed 1.  But you are looking at the wrong field.The document count is 1 because you have 1 document which have the returned results. The actual count is in the result.Value field. Please try it. P.S - I can't comment on your code - but don't return the count property, return the result.Value. which contains the number of documents you need.

Comment: queryResults.Value - is not a property.  Maybe I am doing something wrong - plz be patient with me - I am VERY good w/SQL Server, etc - just new ground for me here.

Comment: @DonRedd I am trying to help, not pushing you or something.
after that ilne
`var queryResults = query.Run();`

you have your results in the queryResults variable which is IEnumerable.
you have to Iterate it. each value in that iterator is object.
In order to have an int- try casting it.

one way of doing it -by Select function.
`var count = queryResults.Select(result => result.Value).First();`
We are assuming that you have exactly one object, as we counting one maker. so we get first.
after that depending on your app, you can cast it to int or string.

Hope it's clearer.

Comment: roikatz, iterating thru the results is exactly what I was doing before I went on this little adventure.  On the server - Reduce is a one line statement.  On CB Lite - it takes a little more code. Looks like I am in fact reducing already by the way I am structuring my Views.

Comment: @DonRedd, But as I see from the code you've pasted in another answer, you are just returning the Count property.